# Can someone please show me how these circuits would look in LTspice? Can you also point out where I need to probe?

Tags: ltspice

Can someone please show me how these would look in Ltspice and what their waveforms should look like? I though I was building them correctly, but they would not work. Could you also point out where to probe the circuits for the requested values? I was not able to probe anywhere for the output voltage on circuit 1. Thank you. 
 [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit confusing, I suggest you edit it and clarify some things. Is this a homework? If so, include the homework tag and show what you have done so far. Did you create the schematic in LTspice and it did not work? Which error did it output? The "requested values" are two results, you don't need to probe for that, you are the one defining its values. You should probe the output pin and check if it is resulting in a 40% duty cycle square wave output.

Comment: I don't understand, you want others to do the work for you? If not, can you prove it?

Comment: please post, what you have tried in LTSpice.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question they have given clear instruction to use 3 diodes in series to represent a red LED and 1048 resistor to represent 1k resistor with 5% tolerance. Connect these and increase the input voltage in steps of 1.5V. Observe the voltage across the diodes and current through the diodes (of course it is single loop, current will be same in the circuit) at each increment. Plot the v-i characteristics. 
[image: Red LED circuit]
I have simulated this in PSpice using DC sweep analysis. The v-i plot across the diodes should look like general v-i characteristics of a diode as shown in the following graph.
[image: v-i characteristics]
Try to do the same experiment with components on a board with all the other known parameters and compare the results.

For the second question you don't need to simulate to get the resistor values. You have 2 required variables, 2 unknown variables and 2 equations. You should be able to solve the equations. Keep in mind if you get non standard resistor values, either you can achieve the resistance using resistor combination or if you want to be cost effective take nearest standard resistor values and recalculate the duty cycle and frequency.